# ¿Por qué no se reconoce la variable?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo una tabla en una base de datos a la cual hago una consulta completa, lo que quiero hacer es un botón de eliminar el cual elimine la fila que quiera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al usar el boton me tira este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código del botón eliminar es este:

```
<?php
EliminarReg($_GET['Matricula']);
function EliminarReg($Matricula) {
    require 'serv.php';
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `registros` WHERE Matricula ='".$Matricula."'";
    $conect->query($sql) or die ("Error al eliminar".mysqli_error($conect));
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert ("Registro Eliminado");
    //window.location.href = 'panel.php';
    </script>
```

El código donde tengo la tabla es este:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'serv.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
 *
 * @author Zarate
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dashboard</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
                <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!--        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>-->
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0; background-image: url(/CuentasDominio/img/ver_full_hd.jpg); background-size: cover; font-family: sans-serif; overflow: visible;">
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-left: 6.5%; margin-right: 6.5%; margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
            <div class="panel-body" style="overflow: auto; height: 545px;">
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="font-size: .8em;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellidos</th>
            <th>Nombre Completo</th>
            <th>Alias E-mail</th>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Puesto</th>
            <th>Delegacion</th>
            <th>Departamento</th>
            <th>Direccion</th>
            <th>Ciudad</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Telefono</th>
            <th>Extension</th>
            <th>Matricula</th>
            <th>CURP</th>
            <th>Num. Seg Social</th>
            <th>Serv. correo actual</th>
            <th>Forma de Acceso</th>
            <th>SO de la PC</th>
            <th>Nombre de la PC</th>
            <th>pwd</th>
            <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    include 'serv.php';
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `registros`";
                $result=$conect->query($sql) or die (mysqli_error($conect));
                //$result = mysqli_query($conect, $sql);
                while (($filas=$result->fetch_assoc())) {
                //while ($filas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Nombre']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Apellidos']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Nombre Completo']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Alias E-mail']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Titulo']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Puesto']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Delegacion']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Departamento']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Direccion']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Ciudad']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Estado']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Telefono']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Extension']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Matricula']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['CURP']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Num. Seg Social']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Servidor de correo actual']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Forma de Acceso']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Sist. Operativo de la PC']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['Nombre de la PC']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>"; echo $filas['pwd']; echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td> <a href='eliminar.php?Matricula = ".$filas['Matricula']."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' style=''>Eliminar</button></a> </td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }    
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="logout.php"><button class="btn btn-warning" style="position: absolute; right: 16.5%; font-size: 1.3em; width: 80px;"> Salir </button></a>
        <!--        <button class="btn btn-success" style="position: absolute; right: 46%; font-size: 1.3em;">Generar .xls</button>-->
        <a href="regisGuar.php"><button class="btn btn-primary" style="position: absolute; right: 6.5%; font-size: 1.3em; width: auto;">Generar .xls</button></a>
    </body>
</html>
    <?php
                }else{
                    echo '<script> window.location="index.php"; </script>';
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: Quizá deberías primero comprobar lo que llega en Matricula, con un **isset**

Comment: Acabo de ver tu posible error: quita los espacios que hay antes y después del signo de igualdad en `Matricula` aquí: **`echo "<td> <a href='eliminar.php?Matricula=".$filas['Matricula']."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' style=''>Eliminar</button></a> </td>";`**. De todos modos, deberías usar `isset`. Y yo haría la operación de eliminación vía Ajax, en background, actualizando el contenido de `panel.php` sin tener que cargar de nuevo la página. Es mucho más elegante. Pero eso es secundario de cara al problema actual.

Comment: no se usar ajax, ya me funciono y siento que era por el espacio aunque en realidad no se que fue porque cambia las variables y la que llamo fue una que agregue como llave primaria aunque no creo que tenga nada que ver que sea primaria o no, saludos y gracias

Comment: Es por las comillas que esta usando. Alli en registros parece $sql = "DELETE FROM `registros` WHERE Matricula ='".$Matricula."'";

Comment: orita ya me funciona, deje esas comillas igual pero se me hace que fue lo primero que me comentaste amigo, sobre el espacio, ahora lo deje, toma el espacio como parte de la variable

Comment: En la imagen se ve claramente que la variable se construye bien, sólo que con los espacios que estabas agregando, quitando esos dos espacios debería funcionar. En cuanto al uso de Ajax, si te interesa, aquí mismo hay algunos ejemplos de su uso, creo que sería la mejor opción en tu caso, porque así no tienes que estar cargando otro archivo diferente para hacer la eliminación. También, sería bueno que des seguridad a tu código, usando consultas preparadas, ya que como tienes tu consulta ahora, podrías ser víctima de Inyección de código en un entorno en producción.